# Ubuntu 14.04 hangs while using Android Studio

Tags: 14.04, android-studio

My laptop is HP Pavilion dv-6 6155tx. And I am new user of Linux. I have installed ubuntu for programming purpose. But when I am using Android Studio with 2 or 3 applications runnning in background. System hangs even I cant move the cursor. I always run my application on phone. I dont use emulator. My phone is Xperia L(C2104). This is not the problem of phone because maximum time it hangs while indexing or gradling the project.

Does anyone know the possible causes of system hanging in these situation ?

Comment: i have the same problem, seems like its common to us all. maybe ill just go back to windows

Comment: same here, could not find any solution for this problem, so i came back to windows 10. now i am good. i really tried hard to accept ubuntu but i was failed.

Answer (score 1):

Does Ubuntu hang when you are not using the Android virtual mobile device emulator? Genymotion is much faster than the Android emulator in Android Studio, and the HP Pavilion dv6-6155tx with its Core i5 processor and 4GB RAM could easily run it.

Since the laptop is hanging when you run your application on the phone, you could try developing your application on a virtual Android OS in Genymotion. This would buy you some time to keep on developing your application, while you try to find out why the phone is making your laptop hang.

Because your existing project is getting stuck in Gradle, I wonder if you created a new project in Android Studio to print something to the screen if it would build properly.

Comment: I have also tried new project. Sir provide me the solution if you can dont make assumptions.

Comment: Try going to the Gradle settings and check Offline Work option, create your project, close your project, uncheck Offline Work, and reopen your project. If Gradle hangs,  force close Android Studio and launch it again. This time, just open the existing project and let it take care of finishing up the process of building/downloading.