# Gradle or Android Studio freezes Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, android, sony, android-studio, gradle

I've got a problem with my Android Studio/Gradle regularly freezing my entire system.

**What happens?**

I work on my Android Studio and at first, everything is ok. For approx 5 - 10 builds/deploys everything is fine but then I click the "Run 'app'" button, as usual, the build starts as usual but suddenly system slows down to the point where it's basically frozen. The disk led indicator on my laptop is flashing like crazy and I can also hear the disk working really hard. I'm not able to switch to different console (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>) and I'm not even able to move the mouse cursor because it's also frozen. It seems like something is swallowing all my laptop's resources. The only thing that helps is forced to shutdown. Once I've tried to wait to see if it helps but after 2 hours I gave up and forcefully shut it down. I've got logs from that incident if needed.

**When did it start?**

It all started when I switched to Ubuntu 16.04. I tried to revert back to 14.04 and as far as I remember everything worked. But then I had to go back to 16.04 (because of problems with Bumblebee and Nvidia drivers) and the problems were back again. Also - As part of moving to 16.04 I had to switch from Bumblebee to newest Nvidia driver (although I'm not sure if this is relevant)

**When does it happen?**

It happens once every few builds (let's say 10). Basically after like 3 hours of work I can guarantee that the system crashes.

**What are you using?**

My system is

- Ubuntu 16.04
- Android Studio 2.3
- Gradle 2.3.0 (Although I do not have Gradle installed in Ubuntu, it's just a dependency in my project)
- Oracle java version "1.8.0_121"
- Linux version 4.4.0-66-generic
- Nvidia driver 367.57
- Intel® Core™ i5-2430M CPU @ 2.40GHz × 4
- GeForce GT 555M/PCIe/SSE2

**What have you tried?**

I tried to alter my Gradle settings in ~/.gradle/gradle.properties to look like this

```
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.parallel=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m
```

Although it didn't help, actually the opposite happened - when I increased Xmx to 2056 the freezing started to happen much sooner, after 2 - 3 builds. I also tried to revert my Nvidia drivers to 304 but it didn't help, freezing was still happening.

**Example**

This incident happened yesterday 2017-03-10 at 22:14. I post a shorter version of logs from that time although I can provide more if needed.

idea.log

```
2017-03-10 22:09:54,288 [8594964]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.gradle.internal.logging.slf4j.OutputEventListenerBackedLoggerContext] 
2017-03-10 22:09:55,254 [8595930]   INFO - pl.ProjectRootManagerComponent - project roots have changed 
2017-03-10 22:09:55,626 [8596302]   INFO - a.gradle.run.MakeBeforeRunTask - Gradle invocation complete, success = true 
2017-03-10 22:09:57,039 [8597715]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Pushing properties took 559ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2017-03-10 22:09:57,238 [8597914]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Indexable file iteration took 199ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2017-03-10 22:09:57,238 [8597914]   INFO - indexing.UnindexedFilesUpdater - Unindexed files update started: 20 files to update 
2017-03-10 22:09:58,159 [8598835]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Unindexed files update took 921ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2017-03-10 22:09:58,345 [8599021]   INFO -                    #InstantRun - $ adb install-multiple -r -p eu.efreet.styrizmeny /home/miro/Development/workspaces/android/StyriZmeny/app/build/outputs/apk/StyriZmeny-0.5.1-debug.apk  
2017-03-10 22:10:05,807 [8606483]   INFO -            #com.android.ddmlib - Opening a debugger listener at port 8600 for client with pid 17916 
2017-03-10 22:10:07,124 [8607800]   INFO - idea.run.AndroidProcessHandler - Adding device sony-d6503-BH91548F16 to monitor for launched app: eu.efreet.styrizmeny 
2017-03-10 22:14:10,281 [8850957]   INFO -                    #InstantRun - Invoking hotswap launch 
2017-03-10 22:14:11,436 [8852112]   INFO -                    #InstantRun - Build timestamps: Local: 1489180140216, Device: 1489180140216 
2017-03-10 22:14:11,587 [8852263]   INFO -                    #InstantRun - Ping sent and replied successfully, application seems to be running. Foreground=true 
2017-03-10 22:14:11,644 [8852320]   INFO -                    #InstantRun - Ping sent and replied successfully, application seems to be running. Foreground=true 
2017-03-10 22:14:11,650 [8852326]   INFO - ild.invoker.GradleBuildInvoker - About to execute Gradle tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] 
2017-03-10 22:14:11,772 [8852448]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle 
2017-03-10 22:14:11,787 [8852463]   INFO - ild.invoker.GradleBuildInvoker - Build command line options: [--configure-on-demand, -Pandroid.injected.invoked.from.ide=true, -Pandroid.injected.build.api=23, -Pandroid.injected.build.density=xxhdpi, -Pandroid.injected.build.abi=armeabi-v7a,armeabi, -Pandroid.injected.restrict.variant.name=debug, -Pandroid.injected.restrict.variant.project=:app, -Pandroid.optional.compilation=INSTANT_DEV, -Pandroid.injected.coldswap.mode=MULTIAPK, --init-script, /tmp/asLocalRepo162.gradle] 
2017-03-10 22:14:11,787 [8852463]   INFO - xecution.GradleExecutionHelper - Passing command-line args to Gradle Tooling API: [--configure-on-demand, -Pandroid.injected.invoked.from.ide=true, -Pandroid.injected.build.api=23, -Pandroid.injected.build.density=xxhdpi, -Pandroid.injected.build.abi=armeabi-v7a,armeabi, -Pandroid.injected.restrict.variant.name=debug, -Pandroid.injected.restrict.variant.project=:app, -Pandroid.optional.compilation=INSTANT_DEV, -Pandroid.injected.coldswap.mode=MULTIAPK, --init-script, /tmp/asLocalRepo162.gradle] 
2017-03-10 22:21:45,458 [      0]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - ------------------------------------------------------ IDE STARTED ------------------------------------------------------ 
2017-03-10 22:21:45,650 [    192]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - IDE: Android Studio (build #AI-162.3764568, 24 Feb 2017 00:00) 
2017-03-10 22:21:45,650 [    192]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - OS: Linux (4.4.0-66-generic, amd64) 
2017-03-10 22:21:45,650 [    192]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-b06 (JetBrains s.r.o) 
2017-03-10 22:21:45,650 [    192]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM: 25.112-b06 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM) 
2017-03-10 22:21:45,706 [    248]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM Args: -Xbootclasspath/a:/home/miro/Development/android-studio/bin/../lib/boot.jar -Xms256m -Xmx1280m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50 -da -Djna.nosys=true -Djna.boot.library.path= -Djna.debug_load=true -Djna.debug_load.jna=true -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd -Djb.vmOptionsFile=/home/miro/Development/android-studio/bin/studio64.vmoptions -XX:ErrorFile=/home/miro/java_error_in_STUDIO_%p.log -XX:HeapDumpPath=/home/miro/java_error_in_STUDIO.hprof -Djb.restart.code=88 -Didea.paths.selector=AndroidStudio2.3 -Didea.platform.prefix=AndroidStudio -Didea.jre.check=true
```

build.log

```
2017-03-10 22:09:37,510 [  24738]   INFO - ellij.util.io.PagedFileStorage - lower=100; upper=500; buffer=10; max=602
2017-03-10 22:09:40,386 [  27614]   INFO - .incremental.IncProjectBuilder - Building project; isRebuild:false; isMake:true parallel compilation:false
2017-03-10 22:09:40,411 [  27639]   INFO - r.api.ClassFilesIndicesBuilder - class files data index disabled
2017-03-10 22:09:53,619 [      0]   INFO - etbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain - Build process started. Classpath: /home/miro/Development/android-studio/lib/jps-launcher.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/lib/tools.jar:/home/miro/Development/android-studio/lib/optimizedFileManager.jar:/home/miro/Development/android-studio/lib/ecj-4.5.2.jar
2017-03-10 22:09:55,962 [   2343]   INFO - etbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain - Connection to IDE established in 2164 ms
2017-03-10 22:09:56,339 [   2720]   INFO - jps.cmdline.JpsModelLoaderImpl - Loading model: project path = /home/miro/Development/workspaces/android/StyriZmeny, global options path = /home/miro/.AndroidStudio2.3/config/options
2017-03-10 22:09:57,502 [   3883]   INFO - jps.cmdline.JpsModelLoaderImpl - Model loaded in 1163 ms
2017-03-10 22:09:57,502 [   3883]   INFO - jps.cmdline.JpsModelLoaderImpl - Project has 2 modules, 25 libraries
2017-03-10 22:09:57,623 [   4004]   INFO - .JpsGradleExtensionServiceImpl - /home/miro/.AndroidStudio2.3/system/compile-server/styrizmeny_5c256e6c/gradle/configuration.xml (No such file or directory)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/miro/.AndroidStudio2.3/system/compile-server/styrizmeny_5c256e6c/gradle/configuration.xml (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.JDOMUtil.load(JDOMUtil.java:279)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.gradle.model.impl.JpsGradleExtensionServiceImpl.getGradleProjectConfiguration(JpsGradleExtensionServiceImpl.java:125)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.gradle.model.impl.JpsGradleExtensionServiceImpl.getGradleProjectConfiguration(JpsGradleExtensionServiceImpl.java:113)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.gradle.model.impl.GradleResourcesTarget.computeRootDescriptors(GradleResourcesTarget.java:69)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.builders.impl.BuildRootIndexImpl.addRoots(BuildRootIndexImpl.java:72)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.builders.impl.BuildRootIndexImpl.<init>(BuildRootIndexImpl.java:62)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.load(BuildRunner.java:84)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:266)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:125)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler$1.run(BuildMain.java:232)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl$1.run(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:44)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2017-03-10 22:09:57,782 [   4163]   INFO - ellij.util.io.PagedFileStorage - lower=100; upper=500; buffer=10; max=602
2017-03-10 22:09:58,128 [   4509]   INFO - .incremental.IncProjectBuilder - Building project; isRebuild:false; isMake:true parallel compilation:false
2017-03-10 22:09:58,132 [   4513]   INFO - r.api.ClassFilesIndicesBuilder - class files data index disabled
2017-03-10 22:23:41,521 [      0]   INFO - etbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain - Build process started. Classpath: /home/miro/Development/android-studio/lib/jps-launcher.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/lib/tools.jar:/home/miro/Development/android-studio/lib/optimizedFileManager.jar:/home/miro/Development/android-studio/lib/ecj-4.5.2.jar
2017-03-10 22:23:44,400 [   2879]   INFO - etbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain - Connection to IDE established in 2694 ms
2017-03-10 22:23:45,069 [   3548]   INFO - jps.cmdline.JpsModelLoaderImpl - Loading model: project path = /home/miro/Development/workspaces/android/StyriZmeny, global options path = /home/miro/.AndroidStudio2.3/config/options
2017-03-10 22:23:47,029 [   5508]   INFO - jps.cmdline.JpsModelLoaderImpl - Model loaded in 1960 ms
2017-03-10 22:23:47,029 [   5508]   INFO - jps.cmdline.JpsModelLoaderImpl - Project has 2 modules, 25 libraries
2017-03-10 22:23:47,395 [   5874]   INFO - .JpsGradleExtensionServiceImpl - /home/miro/.AndroidStudio2.3/system/compile-server/styrizmeny_5c256e6c/gradle/configuration.xml (No such file or directory)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/miro/.AndroidStudio2.3/system/compile-server/styrizmeny_5c256e6c/gradle/configuration.xml (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.JDOMUtil.load(JDOMUtil.java:279)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.gradle.model.impl.JpsGradleExtensionServiceImpl.getGradleProjectConfiguration(JpsGradleExtensionServiceImpl.java:125)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.gradle.model.impl.JpsGradleExtensionServiceImpl.getGradleProjectConfiguration(JpsGradleExtensionServiceImpl.java:113)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.gradle.model.impl.GradleResourcesTarget.computeRootDescriptors(GradleResourcesTarget.java:69)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.builders.impl.BuildRootIndexImpl.addRoots(BuildRootIndexImpl.java:72)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.builders.impl.BuildRootIndexImpl.<init>(BuildRootIndexImpl.java:62)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.load(BuildRunner.java:84)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:266)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:125)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler$1.run(BuildMain.java:232)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl$1.run(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:44)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2017-03-10 22:23:47,489 [   5968]   INFO - ellij.util.io.PagedFileStorage - lower=100; upper=500; buffer=10; max=602
```

syslog

```
Mar 10 22:07:23 miro-msi org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[1714]:       dc04: Object Size UINT64 data type READ ONLY
Mar 10 22:11:23 miro-msi gnome-session[1839]: INFO:root:caffeine is inhibiting desktop idleness
Mar 10 22:11:50 miro-msi gnome-session[1839]: INFO:root:caffeine is no longer inhibiting desktop idleness
Mar 10 22:12:50 miro-msi gnome-session[1839]: INFO:root:caffeine is inhibiting desktop idleness
Mar 10 22:14:51 miro-msi pulseaudio[1891]: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-util.c: snd_pcm_avail() returned a value that is exceptionally large: 439744 bytes (2290 ms).
Mar 10 22:14:51 miro-msi pulseaudio[1891]: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-util.c: Most likely this is a bug in the ALSA driver 'snd_hda_intel'. Please report this issue to the ALSA developers.
Mar 10 22:15:04 miro-msi kernel: [12713.696036] wlp4s0: deauthenticated from 44:55:b1:d8:63:94 (Reason: 16=GROUP_KEY_HANDSHAKE_TIMEOUT)
Mar 10 22:15:03 miro-msi pulseaudio[1891]: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-util.c: snd_pcm_dump():
Mar 10 22:15:05 miro-msi pulseaudio[1891]: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-util.c: Soft volume PCM
Mar 10 22:15:05 miro-msi pulseaudio[1891]: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-util.c: Control: PCM Playback Volume
Mar 10 22:15:07 miro-msi pulseaudio[1891]: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-util.c: min_dB: -51
Mar 10 22:15:08 miro-msi pulseaudio[1891]: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-util.c: max_dB: 0
Mar 10 22:15:08 miro-msi pulseaudio[1891]: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-util.c: resolution: 256
Mar 10 22:15:08 miro-msi pulseaudio[1891]: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-util.c: Its setup is:
Mar 10 22:15:08 miro-msi pulseaudio[1891]: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-util.c:   stream       : PLAYBACK
Mar 10 22:15:09 miro-msi pulseaudio[1891]: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-util.c:   access       : MMAP_INTERLEAVED
Mar 10 22:15:11 miro-msi pulseaudio[1891]: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-util.c:   format       : S16_LE
Mar 10 22:15:11 miro-msi pulseaudio[1891]: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-util.c:   subformat    : STD
Mar 10 22:15:12 miro-msi pulseaudio[1891]: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-util.c:   channels     : 2
Mar 10 22:15:12 miro-msi pulseaudio[1891]: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-util.c:   rate         : 48000
Mar 10 22:15:12 miro-msi pulseaudio[1891]: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-util.c:   exact rate   : 48000 (48000/1)
Mar 10 22:15:12 miro-msi pulseaudio[1891]: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-util.c:   msbits       : 16
Mar 10 22:15:12 miro-msi pulseaudio[1891]: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-util.c:   buffer_size  : 16384
Mar 10 22:15:12 miro-msi pulseaudio[1891]: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-util.c:   period_size  : 8192
Mar 10 22:15:12 miro-msi pulseaudio[1891]: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-util.c:   period_time  : 170666
Mar 10 22:15:12 miro-msi pulseaudio[1891]: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-util.c:   tstamp_mode  : ENABLE
Mar 10 22:15:12 miro-msi pulseaudio[1891]: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-util.c:   tstamp_type  : MONOTONIC
Mar 10 22:15:12 miro-msi pulseaudio[1891]: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-util.c:   period_step  : 1
Mar 10 22:15:13 miro-msi pulseaudio[1891]: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-util.c:   avail_min    : 15665
Mar 10 22:15:18 miro-msi pulseaudio[1891]: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-util.c:   period_event : 0
Mar 10 22:15:20 miro-msi pulseaudio[1891]: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-util.c:   start_threshold  : -1
Mar 10 22:15:20 miro-msi pulseaudio[1891]: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-util.c:   stop_threshold   : 4611686018427387904
Mar 10 22:15:20 miro-msi pulseaudio[1891]: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-util.c:   silence_threshold: 0
Mar 10 22:15:20 miro-msi pulseaudio[1891]: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-util.c:   silence_size : 0
Mar 10 22:15:20 miro-msi pulseaudio[1891]: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-util.c:   boundary     : 4611686018427387904
Mar 10 22:15:20 miro-msi pulseaudio[1891]: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-util.c: Slave: Hardware PCM card 0 'HDA Intel PCH' device 0 subdevice 0
Mar 10 22:15:22 miro-msi pulseaudio[1891]: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-util.c: Its setup is:
Mar 10 22:15:22 miro-msi pulseaudio[1891]: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-util.c:   stream       : PLAYBACK
Mar 10 22:15:22 miro-msi pulseaudio[1891]: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-util.c:   access       : MMAP_INTERLEAVED
Mar 10 22:15:23 miro-msi pulseaudio[1891]: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-util.c:   format       : S16_LE
Mar 10 22:15:23 miro-msi pulseaudio[1891]: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-util.c:   subformat    : STD
Mar 10 22:15:23 miro-msi pulseaudio[1891]: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-util.c:   channels     : 2
Mar 10 22:15:23 miro-msi pulseaudio[1891]: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-util.c:   rate         : 48000
Mar 10 22:15:23 miro-msi pulseaudio[1891]: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-util.c:   exact rate   : 48000 (48000/1)
Mar 10 22:15:24 miro-msi pulseaudio[1891]: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-util.c:   msbits       : 16
Mar 10 22:15:25 miro-msi pulseaudio[1891]: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-util.c:   buffer_size  : 16384
Mar 10 22:15:25 miro-msi pulseaudio[1891]: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-util.c:   period_size  : 8192
Mar 10 22:15:25 miro-msi pulseaudio[1891]: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-util.c:   period_time  : 170666
Mar 10 22:15:25 miro-msi pulseaudio[1891]: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-util.c:   tstamp_mode  : ENABLE
Mar 10 22:15:25 miro-msi pulseaudio[1891]: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-util.c:   tstamp_type  : MONOTONIC
Mar 10 22:15:27 miro-msi pulseaudio[1891]: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-util.c:   period_step  : 1
Mar 10 22:15:27 miro-msi pulseaudio[1891]: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-util.c:   avail_min    : 15665
Mar 10 22:15:27 miro-msi pulseaudio[1891]: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-util.c:   period_event : 0
Mar 10 22:15:27 miro-msi pulseaudio[1891]: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-util.c:   start_threshold  : -1
Mar 10 22:15:27 miro-msi pulseaudio[1891]: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-util.c:   stop_threshold   : 4611686018427387904
Mar 10 22:15:27 miro-msi pulseaudio[1891]: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-util.c:   silence_threshold: 0
Mar 10 22:15:27 miro-msi pulseaudio[1891]: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-util.c:   silence_size : 0
Mar 10 22:15:27 miro-msi pulseaudio[1891]: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-util.c:   boundary     : 4611686018427387904
Mar 10 22:15:27 miro-msi pulseaudio[1891]: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-util.c:   appl_ptr     : 10145784
Mar 10 22:15:27 miro-msi pulseaudio[1891]: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-util.c:   hw_ptr       : 10239336
Mar 10 22:15:39 miro-msi pulseaudio[1891]: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-util.c: snd_pcm_delay() returned a value that is exceptionally large: -9417504 bytes (-49049 ms).
Mar 10 22:15:39 miro-msi pulseaudio[1891]: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-util.c: Most likely this is a bug in the ALSA driver 'snd_hda_intel'. Please report this issue to the ALSA developers.
Mar 10 22:15:49 miro-msi pulseaudio[1891]: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-util.c: snd_pcm_dump():
Mar 10 22:15:50 miro-msi pulseaudio[1891]: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-util.c: Soft volume PCM
Mar 10 22:15:50 miro-msi pulseaudio[1891]: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-util.c: Control: PCM Playback Volume
Mar 10 22:15:50 miro-msi pulseaudio[1891]: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-util.c: min_dB: -51
Mar 10 22:15:50 miro-msi pulseaudio[1891]: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-util.c: max_dB: 0
Mar 10 22:15:50 miro-msi pulseaudio[1891]: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-util.c: resolution: 256
Mar 10 22:15:50 miro-msi pulseaudio[1891]: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-util.c: Its setup is:
Mar 10 22:15:50 miro-msi pulseaudio[1891]: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-util.c:   stream       : PLAYBACK
Mar 10 22:15:53 miro-msi pulseaudio[1891]: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-util.c:   access       : MMAP_INTERLEAVED
Mar 10 22:15:53 miro-msi pulseaudio[1891]: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-util.c:   format       : S16_LE
Mar 10 22:15:53 miro-msi pulseaudio[1891]: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-util.c:   subformat    : STD
Mar 10 22:15:53 miro-msi pulseaudio[1891]: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-util.c:   channels     : 2
Mar 10 22:15:53 miro-msi pulseaudio[1891]: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-util.c:   rate         : 48000
Mar 10 22:15:53 miro-msi pulseaudio[1891]: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-util.c:   exact rate   : 48000 (48000/1)
Mar 10 22:15:53 miro-msi pulseaudio[1891]: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-util.c:   msbits       : 16
Mar 10 22:15:55 miro-msi pulseaudio[1891]: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-util.c:   buffer_size  : 16384
Mar 10 22:15:56 miro-msi pulseaudio[1891]: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-util.c:   period_size  : 8192
Mar 10 22:15:57 miro-msi pulseaudio[1891]: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-util.c:   period_time  : 170666
Mar 10 22:15:57 miro-msi pulseaudio[1891]: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-util.c:   tstamp_mode  : ENABLE
Mar 10 22:15:57 miro-msi pulseaudio[1891]: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-util.c:   tstamp_type  : MONOTONIC
Mar 10 22:15:57 miro-msi pulseaudio[1891]: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-util.c:   period_step  : 1
Mar 10 22:15:58 miro-msi pulseaudio[1891]: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-util.c:   avail_min    : 15665
Mar 10 22:15:59 miro-msi pulseaudio[1891]: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-util.c:   period_event : 0
Mar 10 22:15:59 miro-msi pulseaudio[1891]: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-util.c:   start_threshold  : -1
Mar 10 22:17:01 miro-msi rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.16.0" x-pid="894" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
Mar 10 22:17:00 miro-msi rsyslogd-2222: command 'KLogPermitNonKernelFacility' is currently not permitted - did you already set it via a RainerScript command (v6+ config)? [v8.16.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2222 ]
Mar 10 22:17:01 miro-msi rsyslogd: rsyslogd's groupid changed to 108
Mar 10 22:17:01 miro-msi rsyslogd: rsyslogd's userid changed to 104
Mar 10 22:17:01 miro-msi systemd-modules-load[242]: Inserted module 'lp'
Mar 10 22:17:01 miro-msi systemd-modules-load[242]: Inserted module 'ppdev'
Mar 10 22:17:01 miro-msi systemd-modules-load[242]: Inserted module 'parport_pc'
Mar 10 22:17:01 miro-msi loadkeys[248]: Loading /etc/console-setup/cached.kmap.gz
Mar 10 22:17:01 miro-msi systemd[1]: Started Set console keymap.
Mar 10 22:17:01 miro-msi systemd[1]: Started Create Static Device Nodes in /dev.
Mar 10 22:17:01 miro-msi rsyslogd-2039: Could not open output pipe '/dev/xconsole':: No such file or directory [v8.16.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2039 ]
Mar 10 22:17:01 miro-msi systemd[1]: Starting udev Kernel Device Manager...
Mar 10 22:17:01 miro-msi kernel: [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
Mar 10 22:17:01 miro-msi kernel: [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
Mar 10 22:17:01 miro-msi systemd[1]: Started Apply Kernel Variables.
```

**Questions**

Do you see any problems in the logs? Can I start recording some more detailed logs in Android Studio or in Gradle? One colleague of mine said that my problem sounds like kernel panic, could it be it?

Possible duplicate:

[Ubuntu 14.04 hangs while using Android Studio](https://askubuntu.com/questions/618132/ubuntu-14-04-hangs-while-using-android-studio)

Interesting coincidence - I've also got a Sony phone, just a different model. I've got a Sony Xperia Z2. So maybe this is another clue

Comment: What type of laptop is it?  The laptop could be faulty.

Comment: It's true my laptop is older - it's MSI GE620DX and it's 5 years old. So it might be a HW failure but I don't know ... I'd say I'm not fully convinced yet :) If it's some "bad sector" or something in HDD/RAM I'd say it would crash also during some other things. But this happens specifically in Android Studio and Gradle, everything else seems to be working ok. But thanks, I haven't considered this option. At least I run some disk check tool

Comment: My computer freezes and quits because lack of ram but this is windows and I get a warning before it happens.  You really need 8gb of ram plus for android studio.

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure about that. As I said I used to use Android Studio on Ubuntu 14.04 on the same computer for years and I've got no problems. I understand that Android Studio as every long term software changes its requirements over the time but I haven't done any drastic update (f.e. from 0.7 -> 2.2), I use the same version as in 14.04. Also as you said I would also expect at least some warning (or something to pop up in logs), that's why I'm not sure about this. Just for fun I'll probably install 14.04 on separate partition to see if everything still works there (when I have some free time)

Comment: I believe the introduction of gradle has increased RAM usage.  But I am new to Android development so don't call me an expert.

Comment: Something similar happens to me on macOS sierra, I've tried with two different laptops and the same stuff happens https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46118664/android-studio-3-0-beta-freezing-constantly-on-macos-sierra

Comment: I have the same issue, did you figure out something?

Comment: @Miroslav did you ever solve this?

Comment: @tatsu Unfortunately no, I started using more powerful laptop where I run Virtual device, the problems don't occur in there

Comment: it must've been hardware related. oh well :S

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 14.04 hangs while using Android Studio](https://askubuntu.com/questions/618132/ubuntu-14-04-hangs-while-using-android-studio)

Comment: Definitely not a kernel-panic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do I need to upgrade RAM from 4GB to 8GB for Android development?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1014495/do-i-need-to-upgrade-ram-from-4gb-to-8gb-for-android-development)

Comment: hello @Miroslav. Can you post "free -h" output. Also, what kind of disk are yo suing? I faced this problem sometime ago, the main issue is ram but with proper swap space you will get slow instead of freeze. Swap space should be 2x RAM.

Answer (score 0):

**ITS HIGHLY RECOMMENDED TO USE MORE THAN 8GB RAM "16GB is good" if can afford more than its execellent having support for 3200DDR4**

I have faced same issue wheather my laptop is new.
Kinda good specs.

then, **why it just hanged up/freezed** ??? *well, personally i didn't find any issue regarding any ubuntu system failure or other disk problem.*

After several research i found that this is happening because of **Hardware acceleration issue** with nvidia graphic card. ( when we run the app/emulator )

Must read this once & give a try -[Android emulator](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration)

One can easily fix this issue by 2 solutions if above link cannot resolve problem -

**SOLUTION 1.--------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

1. Go to the tools >> AVD manager and delete your devices .

[image]

2. go to the SDK manager delete API30 /31 latest API (from SDK platform) which one can used to create their AVD DEVICE.
3. also delete (uncheck) "Android SDK build-tools & Android Auto API simulator and other Android simulator related SDK's" from SDK tools.
   [image: see this image]
4. then, apply changes and save then restart android Android studio and again do the same process to install that SDK's.
5. This problem cause if Somehow SDK is get corrupted.
6. after reinstallation of those SDK then restart AS again and now you can recreate your device in AVD manager.
   [image]

> > during AVD device creation must select "Hardware-GLES" under "Graphic" selection.

*now, Your device is ready to run.*

if still problem persist of hang/freezing. go for solution 2-

**SOLUTION 2------------------------------------------------------------------**
(save your project and reinstall complete android studio-)

*I must suggest you to install with a good speed internet (wired) connection. "slow internet is probeblomatic"*

1. after uninstallation of android studio do perform cleaning as follows-

> ```
> sudo apt-get autoremove
>
> sudo apt-get autoclean
>
> sudo apt-get update
> ```

- then, install android studio using **Ubuntu software** or whichever software store you have.
- after,  installation must update your SDK's which i mentioned in earlier solution.

**-----------------------------Some Additional troubleshooting method/resources---------------------**

- [Troubleshooting EMULATOR](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-troubleshooting)
- [GPU emulation](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-speed-up-android-emulator/)
- [AMD processor support](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/07/android-emulator-amd-processor-hyper-v.html)