# Optimizing 4GB RAM for Android development using Android Studio 4 on Linux

Tags: 20.04, android, performance

I am using `Android Studio 4` on `Ubuntu 20.04 LTS` with Intel Corei3 Processor(`Intel® Core™ i3-2120 CPU @ 3.30GHz × 4`). After starting Android Studio, more than 90% of physical memory gets used. I am not even using any virtual Device with it but connecting my android phone  by USB to my PC.

I have run a `Hard Disk Health Check` and  `Memtest86` to ensure that the RAM and hard disk is not faulty. None of the two reports any errors.

### Hard Disk Health Check:

```
SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000b   100   100   016    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0005   136   136   054    Pre-fail  Offline      -       93
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0007   121   121   024    Pre-fail  Always       -       190 (Average 190)
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       3937
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   096   096   005    Pre-fail  Always       -       249
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000b   100   100   067    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0005   115   115   020    Pre-fail  Offline      -       34
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       4904
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   060    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       3937
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   097   097   000    Old_age   Always       -       4568
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0012   097   097   000    Old_age   Always       -       4568
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0002   181   181   000    Old_age   Always       -       33 (Min/Max 18/49)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   093   093   000    Old_age   Always       -       310
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0008   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x000a   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged
```

Complete report is [here](https://pastebin.com/AsJJcQmN)

### Memtest86:

[image: Memtest86]

### studio64.vmoptions:

```
# Runs JVM in Server mode with more optimizations and resources usage
# It may slow down the startup, but if you usually keep IDE running for few hours/days
# JVM may profile and optimize IDE better. Feel free to remove this flag.
# -server

#Sets the initial memory allocation pool
-Xms512m

#Sets the maximum  memory allocation pool
-Xmx1G

# Sets the size of the allocated class metadata space that will trigger a GC the first time it
# is exceeded, default max value is 350m
-XX:MetaspaceSize=512m
```

### Question:

How do I optimize the physical memory or do I really need to consider increasing the system memory(RAM)?

I have gone through [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1014495/do-i-need-to-upgrade-ram-from-4gb-to-8gb-for-android-development) post but really looking if we have any other workaround.

### Edit:

free.h output

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          3.5Gi       3.0Gi       122Mi       136Mi       405Mi       161Mi
Swap:         2.0Gi       675Mi       1.3Gi
```

Comment: What makes you think it is a problem that all memory is in use?  Please update your question with the output of `free -h` .

Comment: @SorenA - Updated

Comment: @karel: As I had mentioned, I have gone through your answer on the other post. So, there is absolutely no other workaround other than a RAM upgrade?

Comment: The listed specs for Android Studio are not fake news. You should expect to get not better than minimal performance from minimal hardware requirements and you should expect to get recommended performance from recommended hardware requirements.

Comment: I modified `/etc/default/grub` : `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash zswap.enabled=1 zswap.compressor=lz4 zswap.max_pool_percent=25 zswap.zpool=z3fold"` and see how this works.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using Power `save mode` (File -> Power Save Mode)

Do use a physical device for testing.
And finally, reduce Maximum heap size to some lesser value (Help -> Change Memory Settings)

[image: Memory settings]

Hope this helps.

Edit: As you have already changed memory settings, the power-saving mode can help you.