# unable to start android emulator due to kvm error code:0x80000021

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, android-emulator

I would want to run android emulator inside a virtual machine and below are the system (host and guest) details. When I start the emulator, it crashes immediately with the error message "KVM: entry failed, hardware error 0x80000021" (more details about the error, at the end of the question). Can someone provide suggestions to resolve the problem?

Host is *11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1165G7 @ 2.80GHz, 2803 Mhz, 4 Core(s), 8 Logical Processor(s) running windows 10 with virtualization enabled*. Virtualbox guest is *ubuntu 18.04 4 CPUs with "Enable PAE/NX and Enable Nested VT-x/AMD-v" checked*. Android emulator *Android emulator version 31.2.9.0 (build_id 8316981)* is running in the ubuntu virtual machine.

HW virtualization is enabled in the virtual box using below options.

`VBoxManage.exe modifyvm <vm_name> --nested-hw-virt on` and
`VBoxManage.exe modifyvm <vm_name>  --vtxux on`

Below is the complete error message when the emulator crashes.

> KVM: entry failed, hardware error 0x80000021

> If you're running a guest on an Intel machine without unrestricted mode
> support, the failure can be most likely due to the guest entering an invalid
> state for Intel VT. For example, the guest maybe running in big real mode
> which is not supported on less recent Intel processors.

> ERROR   | crashhandler_die: fatal: kvm_arch_handle_exit: hardware error happened in KVM, aborting now

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: Just to confirm, this is a VM inside a VM? What sort of hardware are you using?

Comment: This ^^^ Android emulator uses some virtualization features. It probably needs nested virtualization to work inside a VM.

Comment: Host is **11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1165G7 @ 2.80GHz, 2803 Mhz, 4 Core(s), 8 Logical Processor(s)** running windows 10 with virtualization enabled.
Virtualbox guest is **ubuntu 18.04 4 CPUs with "Enable PAE/NX and Enable Nested VT-x/AMD-v" checked**.
Android emulator **Android emulator version 31.2.9.0 (build_id 8316981)** is running in the ubuntu virtual machine.

Comment: @Community question updated with details. Please let me know if you want more info. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do I need to upgrade RAM from 4GB to 8GB for Android development?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1014495/do-i-need-to-upgrade-ram-from-4gb-to-8gb-for-android-development)

Comment: @karel, The link you have provided is primarily about performance degrade, while in my case the emulator crashes immediately after starting. Still, let me try the suggestions provided in the link and update you further. Thanks for your suggestion.